# Is there a problem with canonical forms for ratios?

Tags: ratio

High school maths and [ratios at KA](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/pre-algebra-ratios-rates?t=practice) show how to solve ratio problems, and when ratios are equivalent - but don't say what the ratio *is*.

I've worked out some canonical forms, and I wondered why something like this isn't used, when they seem to underlie what is taught. Have I got them correct, and is there a problem with the idea of using canonical forms for ratios?

- **Naturals**: the canonical form of a ratio is $p:q$ with $p, q \in \mathbf{N}$ are in lowest terms. This canonical form isn't a number itself, but can only be expressed as a ratio of numbers.

  Another ratio is equivalent to a canonical if both sides are the same multiple of the canonical's sides i.e. $m.p:m.q$ with $m \in \mathbf{N}$. So $4:3$ is *the* ratio, and $8:6$ and $16:12$ are equivalent. But there's no $m$ to give $10$ on the left (and the "corect" right side, $7\frac{1}{2}$, wouldn't be natural anyway).
- **Rationals**: a canonical form of the ratio $p:q$ is the rational number $\frac{p}{q}$, again with with $p, q \in \mathbf{N}$ in lowest terms. This canonical form is simply a rational number.

  These are the "same" ratios as for naturals, but with additional equivalent ratios, because we can multiply by a rational instead of by a natural. i.e.  $\frac{m}{n}.p:\frac{m}{n}.q$ where $m,n \in \mathbf{N}$ - which is equivalent to multiplying, dividing, or multiplying *and* dividing by naturals.
- **Reals**: the canonical form of a ratio $p:q$, where $p,q \in \mathbf{R}$ is simply the real quotient $\frac{p}{q}$. This canonical form is simply a real number.

  A ratio is equivalent to a canonical form if its quotient equals the canonical form.

(I've omitted negatives because they don't seem to be used. They are straightforward to add, but make it less clear.)

Wikipedia's [article on ratios](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio) mentions using the real quotient - but that's not how it's taught.

Perhaps it's a hangover from Euclid, who presented [integral ratios (Book VII, D20)](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVII/defVII20.html) separately from [rational (and kinda irrational) ratios, (Book V, D5)](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookV/defV5.html)? Though he doesn't use canonical forms either. (BTW the wiki ratio article has a nice overview, in [History and etymology, Euclid's Definitions](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Euclid's_definitions)).

Comment: `canonical forms for ratios` Define "*canonical form*". Certain forms make better sense in certain contexts, for example there is no clear universal "winner" between $1 / \sqrt{2}$ vs. $\,\sqrt{2} / 2\,$. `Reals: ...simply the real quotient` But reals include all rationals, which in turn include all integers, so this contradicts the previous points. Also, $\,4 \pi / 2 \pi = 2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv a canonical form is a form to which all instances can be converted uniquely (uniquely in that, for each instance, there is only one possible canonical form). Alt: a nominated instance of a set of equivalent instances. OK, thanks, I see canonical forms might cause disagreement in gemeral, but here specifically, "lowest terms" and "quotiemt" are clear winners, aren't they? e.g. isn't a rational in lowest terms already accepted as a canonical form?

Comment: `isn't a rational in lowest terms already accepted as a canonical form` Generally so, with the denominator usually assumed to be positive. But you run into far worse ambiguities once you step into the reals and beyond.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, you can use the real canonical form for naturals (etc), but that doesn't prevent another canonical form defined just for integers, does it?. I was treating them separately as that is how they seem to be taught. A separate definition for each domain, like integer addition being `closed` over the integers or functions of different domains,  That is, there are `integer_ratio`s, `rational_ratio`s, and `real_ratio`s.

Comment: Real ratio obviously exist. What I am not clear on is what you'd propose as a "*canonical form*" for them.

Comment: @dxiv So, according to these definitions, $4\pi:2\pi$ isn't an `integer_ratio`. To support this notion, Euclid also has an integer-only definition of ratios (7,D20, linked in Q) (Though I agree that having several different "canonical forms" isn't very "canonical".) But I think I can read your reply as saying, in general, canonical forms have problems, so there's a general reluctance to use them by mathematicians - even if they'd be OK for this specific case of ratios.  And even though I think I can answer your specific objections, they add complexity, and aren't as clear as I'd thought.

Comment: [sry, we crossed replies - all of mine have been to your first comment]

Comment: `I think I can read your reply as saying, in general, canonical forms have problems, so there's a general reluctance to use them by mathematicians` No, that's not what I meant. Canonical forms do in fact exist in many legitimate cases. I just don't see how a canonical form for arbitrary real ratios would be defined.

Comment: @dxiv `what you'd propose as a "canonical form" for [real ratios]` Oh, I see. A "canonical _form_" is usually a syntactical construct, i.e. how it is written. But I was thinking of a ratio of two reals e.g. $\pi : e$ being represented by the single real of their quotient e.g. $\frac{\pi}{e}$ (the real number it evaluates to, that we can't notate directly). Now I see why you asked me to define "canonical form"!

Comment: I had checked this part of the definition with wikipedia [*for a class of objects on which an equivalence relation is defined, a **canonical form** consists in the choice of a specific object in each class.*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form), but unfortunately skimmed all its other parts and examples of "presentation". I can still read it with my meaning, but that's not the usual meaning. Is there a term for what I mean? Maybe, "canonical instance"?